# How to group_by and calculate percentage using Cypher queries in Neo4j

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher

I have 3 nodes created in graph database, origin airport and destination airport and carrier. They are related by a property named 'canceled_by'.

```
   MATCH (origin:origin_airport {name: row.ORIGIN}),
   (destination:dest_airport {name: row.DEST}),
   (carrier:Carrier {name: row.UNIQUE_CARRIER})
   CREATE (origin)-[:cancelled_by {cancellation: row.count}]->(carrier)
   CREATE (origin)-[:cancelled_by {cancellation: row.count}]->(destination)
   CREATE (origin)-[:operated_by {carrier: row.UNIQUE_CARRIER}]->(carrier)
```

cancelled_by holds the value number of times particular carrier is cancelled. My input file will be of below format:

```
ORIGIN  UNIQUE_CARRIER  DEST    Cancelled
 ABE    DL                ATL    1
 ABE    EV                ATL    1
 ABE    EV                DTW    3
 ABE    EV                ORD    3
 ABQ    DL                DFW    2
 ABQ    B6                JFK    2
```

Here I need to calculate the cancellation percentage of each carrier. I am expecting result as below:

```
UNIQUE_CARRIER  DEST    Percentage_Cancelled
    DL                   25%
    EV                   58.33%
    B6                   16.66%

Example: Total number of cancellation = 12
No of cancellation for DL = 3
Percentage of cancellation for DL = (3/12)*100 = 25%
```

Below query gives the sum of cancellation for each carrier:

```
 MATCH ()-[ca:cancelled_by]->(c:Carrier)
 RETURN c.name  AS Carrier, 
 SUM(toFloat(ca.cancellation)) As sum
 ORDER BY sum DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

I tried the below query for calculating percentage:

```
  MATCH ()-[ca:cancelled_by]->(c:Carrier)
  WITH SUM(toFloat(ca.cancellation)) As total
  MATCH ()-[ca:cancelled_by]->(c:Carrier)
  RETURN c.name  AS Carrier, 
  (toFloat(ca.cancellation)/total)*100 AS percent
  ORDER BY percent DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

But it is not calculating percentage by grouping and instead calculating the percentage individually.

```
     Carrier    sum
        DL    0.36862408915559364
        DL    0.34290612944706383
        DL    0.3171881697385341
```

How to calculate percentage based on group_by using cypher queries in Neo4j?

Comment: http://coursera.org?

Comment: yup. will be signing up. In the mean time, trying some queries on my own to get used to it. You have any suggestion for above issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the summation by every carrier when grouping, and not necessarily always use a cast to float - just when the last calculation multiplied by the floating-point number.

```
MATCH ()-[ca:cancelled_by]->(:Carrier)
  WITH SUM(ca.cancellation) As total
  MATCH ()-[ca:cancelled_by]->(c:Carrier)
RETURN c.name AS Carrier, 
       100.0 * SUM(ca.cancellation) / total AS percent
  ORDER BY percent DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You could try using the `R` `dplyr` package.
Use the chaining operation `%>%` along with the functions
`group_by`, `summarize` and `transmute`. The `group_by`and `summarize`
will give you the sum of cancelled within each group. Use the
`transmute` function to get relative frequencies.

Comment: I am trying this using cypher queries in Neo4j

Comment: Oh sorry. I saw the R tag and thought about an R solution.