# calculation of percentage from a column is table neo4j/Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to calculate percentage of how much each type of skill is present for each occupation.
I made a have different nodes occupation and Soft_skills they have an relationship [r:MAPS_TO] the relationship has two property type('essentieel', 'optioneel')and b (this kind of weight essentieel =1.0 and optioneel =0.5)

see below een example of the file that i'm using

| occupation | code_occupation | skill_code | name | type | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dokter | sk_565 | sk_687 | leren | optioneel | 0.5 |
| dokter | sk_565 | sk_687 | leren | optioneel | 0.5 |
| dokter | sk_565 | sk_687 | leren | essentieel | 1.0 |
| dokter | sk_565 | sk_687 | leren | essentieel | 1.0 |

i made a query where i can calculate what the sum is for each occupation see below my query:

```
match (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]-(s:Soft_Skill)                                                     
return b.beroepstitel as beroep,                             
sum(toFloat(r.b)) as sum order by sum desc                         
limit 10
```

this is my output

| beroep | sum |
| --- | --- |
| Doker | 5 |
| Kapper | 7 |

know i want to achieve what the percentage is of the type of skill my calculation will be

```
Dokter have in total 4 skills en the percentage of each skill is 
2/4 * 100 = 50% essentieel 
1/4 * 100 = 25% optioneel 

i was trying to make a new calculation with this query:

  MATCH (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]->(s:Soft_skill)
  WITH SUM(toFloat(r.b)) As total
  MATCH (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]->(s:Soft_Skill)
  RETURN b.beroepstitel  AS beroep, 
  (toFloat(total/(r.b)))*100 AS percent
  order by percent desc
```

My output is Cannot divide 'Long' by 'string'
I don't understand the erorr

i was inspired by this question and answer
Here's an inline link to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902749/how-to-group-by-and-calculate-percentage-using-cypher-queries-in-neo4j).

Comment: Why is this question tagged to [r]?

Comment: @wackojacko1997 sorry for that removed the tag

Comment: Can you provide the data of the nodes and relationships, you are using for this example? It is unclear to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MAPS_TO` relationships apparently store the `b` property as a string, so any query must always convert it to a float to do math with it. Also, the math in your query is wrong - `r.b` should be in the numerator and `total` should be in the denominator.

This query may work for you:

```
MATCH (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]->(s:Soft_Skill)
WITH b.beroepstitel AS beorep, r.type AS type, s.name AS skill, SUM(TOFLOAT(r.b)) AS weight
WITH SUM(weight) As total, COLLECT([beorep, type, skill, weight]) AS data
UNWIND data AS datum
RETURN
  datum[0] AS beroep,
  datum[1] AS type,
  datum[2] AS skill,
  datum[3]/total*100 AS percent
ORDER BY percent desc
```

The first `WITH` clause sums all the weights for a given `beorep`, `type`, and `skill`. The second `WITH` clause calculates a total of all the weights and collects all the other data needed. The rest of the query is straightforward.

Here is a sample result:

```
╒════════╤════════════╤═══════╤═════════════════╕
│beroep  │type        │skill  │percent          │
╞════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════╡
│"dokter"│"essentieel"│"leren"│66.66666666666666│
├────────┼────────────┼───────┼─────────────────┤
│"dokter"│"optioneel" │"leren"│33.33333333333333│
└────────┴────────────┴───────┴─────────────────┘
```

##### Recommendations

1. If you stored the `b` property as a float instead of a string, you can avoid the cost of doing `TOFLOAT` conversions all the time. You can easily convert all the stored weights this way:

   ```
   MATCH ()-[r:MAPS_TO]->()
   SET r.b = TOFLOAT(r.b)
   ```
2. If `type` only has 2 possible values, it would require less storage space to store that property as a boolean (named, say, `isRequired`) instead. This can also simplify queries using that property. You can easily convert that property this way:

   ```
   MATCH ()-[r:MAPS_TO]->()
   SET r.isRequired = CASE r.type WHEN 'essentieel' THEN true ELSE false END
   REMOVE r.type
   ```

Comment: you answer is correct only ik get know instead off 24.91 % i get 0.249 what can i improve to get 24.91 % @cybersam

Comment: Your query needs to multiply the quotient by 100, as shown in my answer.

Comment: i did that as well but still get 0.49  ? Is there something wrong in my query ?                                                                    
MATCH (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]->(s:Soft_Skill)
WITH b.beroepstitel AS beroep, r.type AS type, s.omschrijving_soft_skill AS skill, SUM(TOFLOAT(r.b)) AS weight
WITH SUM(weight) As total, COLLECT([beroep, type, skill, weight]) AS data
UNWIND data AS datum
RETURN
  datum[0] AS beroep,
  datum[1] AS type,
  datum[2] AS skill,
  datum[3]/total* 100 AS percent
ORDER BY percent desc

Comment: Are you sure that 0.49 percent is not the real answer?

Comment: No i really get 0.49 % percent how i i want to collect is example: Beroep dokter has 19 skills 5 are optional( weight 1.0)  this means 5 in total. Beroep has 19 skills so means = 5/19 = 0,26*100 = 26% but i get 0.49. So i think there is not oke in the query and i tried everthing. Do you have any idea @cybersam

Comment: I am not seeing an issue using your sample data, so not sure how to advise you. As a guess, there may be oddities in your actual data or in your actual code.

Comment: You where right there was a bug in my data, i looked again with my collega to my data and there was an bug in my data. The query was perfect, thank you so much for your help and quik responce @cybersam

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you may want something like this:

```
MATCH (b:BOC_beroep)-[r:MAPS_TO]->(s:Soft_Skill)
WITH SUM(1) AS total, r.type AS type, COLLECT(r.b) AS type_sum
WITH REDUCE(total=0, number in type_sum | total + number) AS type_sum, type, total
WITH COLLECT ({type: type, type_sum: toFloat(type_sum)}) AS data, SUM(total) AS total
UNWIND data AS d
WITH d.type_sum / total * 100 AS percent, d.type AS type
RETURN percent, type
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

Which for sample data:

```
MERGE (a1:BOC_beroep {occupation: 'dokter', code_occupation: 'sk_565'})  
MERGE (a2:Soft_Skill {skill_code: 'sk_687', name: 'leren'}) 
MERGE (a1)-[:MAPS_TO{type:"optioneel", b:0.5, k:1}]-(a2)
MERGE (a1)-[:MAPS_TO{type:"optioneel", b:0.5, k:2}]-(a2)
MERGE (a1)-[:MAPS_TO{type:"essentieel", b:1, k:3}]-(a2)
MERGE (a1)-[:MAPS_TO{type:"essentieel", b:1, k:4}]-(a2)
```

Returns:

```
╒═════════╤════════════╕
│"percent"│"type"      │
╞═════════╪════════════╡
│50.0     │"essentieel"│
├─────────┼────────────┤
│25.0     │"optioneel" │
└─────────┴────────────┘
```